# Find rows based on non unique column in MySql

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
Column1 | Column2
10      | 200 
10      | 201
11      | 100
11      | 200
11      | 300
12      | 200
13      | 100
13      | 200
13      | 201
13      | 300
```

I wish to extract all rows where column2 contains the value 200 and 201 for each unique column1. The output should be:

```
10      | 200 
10      | 201
13      | 200
13      | 201
```

The table contains about 8 million rows and all the things I can come up with are rather slow.

Comment: What about `11 | 200` ?

Comment: Only combinations of unique column1 and column2 containing 200 and 201 should be returned. Since there is no     11 | 201 this record should not be returned.

Comment: Would you be satisfied if output was  `10 | 2`, `13 | 2`? Or `10 | 200 | 201`, `13 | 200 | 201`

Comment: I need the values 10 and 13. The format doesn't really matter.

Comment: Then, as we commented below, use only inner query, the one being joined. It will return only those who have both 200 and 201.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      Column1
    FROM
      t
    WHERE
      Column2 IN (200,201)
    GROUP BY
      Column1
    HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)>1) AS c
    ON t.Column1=c.Column1
```

-but note, this will output rows with all `Column2` values (i.e. not only `200` and `201`) if it's not an intention, filter them:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      Column1
    FROM
      t
    WHERE
      Column2 IN (200,201)
    GROUP BY
      Column1
    HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)>1) AS c
    ON t.Column1=c.Column1
WHERE
  Column2 IN (200,201)
```

fiddle is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/348c4/3).

Comment: +1 because I wanted to write the same, but then I figured that it might be very slow with 8M rows as pointed out by OP. So I asked if he can adjust his requirement, since it makes sense to output only `Column1` because when you output it it is certain that it has 200 and 201 with it. It would eliminate the need for two queries.

Comment: Precisely. Second query _will produce_ desired output but makes little sense since it's result can be easily produced from subquery with 200 and 201 values only (in application, for example). In fact, that's why only first query is useful (so I left it)

Comment: Very nice, on our server this query takes about 0.1 second to complete. Which is very acceptable.